# ERROR Error uploading profile picture: [FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.]

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I’m developing a React Native app using Expo and attempting to upload a profile picture to Firebase Storage using Expo’s ImagePicker. The app allows users to take a photo or choose one from their library and then upload the selected image to Firebase Storage.

However, I’m encountering a FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions error when attempting to upload the image. The error occurs in the uploadImageToStorage function, specifically when calling uploadBytesResumable to upload the image to Firebase Storage.

```
    const handleTakePhoto = async () => {
        const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== "granted") {
            alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
            return;
        }

        const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [1, 1],
            quality: 0.2,
        });

        if (result.canceled) {
            // Handle cancellation
        } else if (result.type === 'dismissed') {
            // MainActivity was destroyed, get the pending result
            const pendingResult = await ImagePicker.getPendingResultAsync();
            if (!pendingResult.cancelled) {
                uploadImageToStorage(pendingResult.assets[0].uri);
            }
        } else {
            uploadImageToStorage(result.assets[0].uri);
        }
    };

    const handleChooseFromLibrary = async () => {
        const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== "granted") {
            alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
            return;
        }

        const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [1, 1],
            quality: 0.2,
        });

        if (!result.canceled) {
            uploadImageToStorage(result.assets[0].uri);
        }
    };

    const uploadImageToStorage = async (uri) => {
        const user = auth.currentUser;
        const imageName = `profile-picture-${user.uid}`;
        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const storageRef = ref(
            storage,
            `users/${user.uid}/profilePictures/${imageName}`
        );

        try {
            const snapshot = await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blob);
            const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);

            // Update profile and database with the new photoURL
            await updateProfile(user, { photoURL: downloadURL });
            await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), { photoURL: downloadURL });

            // Update the profile picture state and close the modal
            setProfilePic(downloadURL);
            addProfilePicModalRef.current.close();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error uploading profile picture: ", error);
        }
    };

    const handleDeleteProfilePic = async () => {
        const user = auth.currentUser;
        const storageRef = ref(
            storage,
            `users/${user.uid}/profilePictures/profile-picture-${user.uid}`
        );
        try {
            await deleteObject(storageRef);
            await updateProfile(user, { photoURL: null });
            await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), { photoURL: null });
            setProfilePic(null);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error deleting profile picture: ", error);
        }
    };
```

Firebase security rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /profile/{userId}/profile-pic/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your security rules path doesn't match the path in the app code.  Here is the pattern your rules allow:

```
match /profile/{userId}/profile-pic/{allPaths=**} {
```

Here is the pattern in your code:

```
`users/${user.uid}/profilePictures/${imageName}`
```

"profile" is not the same as "users", and "profile-pic" is not the same as "profilePictures", so the rule will reject the upload.